# Error in java using Scanner with double

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I just started studying java and I can't solve an error on my own.
I wrote a code, which purpose is to transform the result of an operation between two variables of "double" type in to an integer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SommaApprossimata {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        double n1, n2;

        int risultato;

        System.out.println("Inserisci due numeri frazionari:");

        n1 = input.nextDouble();

        n2 = input.nextDouble();

        risultato = (int) n1 + (int) n2;

        System.out.print("Il risultato è: " + risultato);

    }

}
```

So I have two variables (n1 and n2) of "double" type, and the result of the operation (risultato) must be presented as an integer.

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

If I don't use Scanner the transformation works!

```
public class SommaApprossimataSemplice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double n1, n2;

        int risultato;

        n1 = 3.3;

        n2 = 4.5;

        risultato = (int) n1 + (int) n2;

        System.out.print("Il risultato è: " + risultato);

    }

}
```

Can you explain it to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you provided input to the Scanner after running your program ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a localization issue (your current seems Italian) with the decimal point being a comma instead of a dot. Try setting the `Locale` of the `Scanner`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the input as `3,3` instead of `3.3`.

Comment: You're totally right, I used 3,3 instead of 3.3 and it works :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an error with your code.

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
```

This error can happen if you provided a wrong input when you run the program, for example a string value instead of numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SommaApprossimata {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        double n1, n2;

        int risultato;

        System.out.println("Inserisci due numeri frazionari:");

        n1 = input.nextDouble();

        n2 = input.nextDouble();

        risultato = (int) n1 + (int) n2;

        System.out.print("Il risultato è: " + risultato);

    }

}

Output :

//save as : SommaApprossimata.java
//compile as :javac SommaApprossimata.java
//run as : java SommaApprossimata 

Inserisci due numeri frazionari:
2.0
3.0
Il risultato Φ: 5
```

As I have run the code it is giving output correctly.

But if you are getting error as java.util.InputMismatchException then it might be that you are giving other format input else than double.

Have a look -

```
Inserisci due numeri frazionari:
abcd
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
        at d.main(d.java:16)
```